# Is there any way to track the logout time in netsuite?

Tags: netsuite

Is it possible to have the logout time in netsuite if a person closes the PC without login out from netsuite?
We need to record the employee(user) check in and check out time in a custom HR module.

Answer (score 1):

You can create a saved search based on email id you want to track the check in and check out time of user - Setup -> User/Roles -> View login Audit Trail , get that saved search in in a suitescript and set it in a field on employee record

Comment: i tried doing the same, but sometimes user switch off PC without logging out and this not reflecting in the Audit trail. is there any way to fetch that time?